# MongoDB C# foreach BsonElement

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a C# class that I instantiate and use to do CRUD operations in a collection

```
public class Property
{
   [BsonId]
   public long id { get; set; }

   [BsonElement("address_line")]
   public string address_line { get; set; }
   [BsonElement("city")]
   public string city { get; set; }
   [BsonElement("zip")]
   public string zip { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to use a foreach loop and construct an update command using $set without specifying each element, something like this:

```
var updateValues = new List<UpdateBuilder>();

foreach (var element in property.Elements)
    updateValues.Add(Update.Set(element.Name, element.Value));

collection.Update(Query.EQ("_id", property.id), Update.Combine(updateValues));
```

I this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
var updateValues = new List<UpdateBuilder>();

foreach (var element in property.ToBsonDocument().Elements)
{
   if (element.Name != "_id") 
   { 
       updateValues.Add(Update.Set(element.Name, element.Value));
   }
}

collection.Update(Query.EQ("_id", property.id), Update.Combine(updateValues));
```

Not sure if there is a better solution, this avoids chaining .Set() commands, although I need to check if the element is not read-only like _id