# MongoDB.Driver.UpdateDefinition from json string

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Can i deserialize json string to MongoDB.Driver.UpdateDefinition
I try:

```
var updateData="{'Description':'Big Description'}";
var obj = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<UpdateDefinition<BsonDocument>>(updateData);
```

But it not work(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot instantiate `UpdateDefinition<T>` since it's an **abstract** class. You can get an instance of `JsonUpdateDefinition` which represents update operation by using below code:

```
var updateData = "{'Description':'Big Description'}";
var obj = new JsonUpdateDefinition<BsonDocument>(updateData);
```

You should also check whether you want to replace existing document using above update definition or just set single field. In that case you need [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator.

Comment: Can i use $set without chaining, if i need update many fields?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641004/mongodb-c-sharp-foreach-bsonelement